# How do I correctly return a substring on a field with a multiple byte character in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, byte, ascii, substr

Hopefully I phrased that question clearly.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I need to parse certain data out of a large varchar field in DB2.

The table name is VCCV013A_DLTA_TERA. The field name is X_ROW_TBL.

Here is a sample of the data found in X_ROW_TBL including the spaces found at the end (The "X"s are replacing certain sensitive data that I didn't want to post here):

```
���pÃd%MERLN      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ��� ��� ��� ��� ���
```

I would expect that this query:

```
select rtrim(substr(x_row_tbl,8,8))
from ti_dev.VCCV013A_DLTA_TERA;
```

Would return this result:

```
MERLN
```

However, it returns:

```
%MERLN
```

The reason appears to be that it is recognizing the "Ã" (ascii 195) character as being two bytes long. My question is: how do I write this query in such a way that I can retrieve the characters starting at position 8, instead of the bytes?

Thank a lot!

Comment: What's the DB2 version and platform, and the database codepage?

Comment: @mustaccio, the version is  DB2 v10.5.0.5, Fix pack 5. OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7. I am not sure how to view the codepage - is there a query I can run to view that info? Thanks!

Comment: `db2 get db cfg for <yourdb> | grep code` or `select name, value from sysibmadm.dbcfg where name like 'code%'`